openssl certificate signing: subject line not copied
When I create CSR, I have the subject line specified.
$ openssl req -in csr -noout -text
...
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Subject: CN = 12345-67890, serialNumber = 67890, 1.3.5.7.9.24.6.8 = 1234
...

$ openssl ca -verbose -config signer.cnf -in csr -out output.crt
...
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Subject: CN = 12345-67890, serialNumber = 67890, 1.3.5.7.9.24.6.8 = 1234
...
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature ok
The Subject's Distinguished Name is as follows
commonName        :ASN.1 12:'12345-67890'
serialNumber      :PRINTABLE:'67890'
1.3.5.7.9.24.6.8  :ASN.1 12:'1234'
Everything appears to be ok, creating and signing the certificate
Successfully added extensions from config
The subject name appears to be ok, checking data base for clashes
Certificate is to be certified until Jun  1 16:48:27 2025 GMT (365 days)
Sign the certificate? [y/n]:

But when I check output.crt, the subject line is empty "Subject:   ".
Below is config "signer.cnf".
[ ca ]
default_ca = my_ca

[ my_ca ]
dir = .
certs = $dir
new_certs_dir = $dir
database = index.txt
serial = serial
private_key = ...
certificate = ...
default_days = 365
policy = my_policy
x509_extensions = my_extensions
copy_extensions = copy

[ my_extensions ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

[ my_policy ]


@garethTheRed, Thank you, it helps!

You [ policy ] section is empty.
From the openssl-ca man pages:

Any fields not mentioned in the policy section are silently deleted, unless the -preserveDN option is set

The -preserveDN option is a command line option.  The equivalent in the config file is to add preserve to your [ my_ca ] section.
